# Storing in flat files and keep track of them?

Tags: java

Let me reword my question. I'm making an application, desktop one for now, a budget tracker. I do not want to use a DBMS like mysql or studio as that would require a server. So my options are flat files, sqlite, and what else can I use besides them?

Comment: At the risk of being pedantic, a flat file is a database.

Comment: well, I think DBs are so many and so easy nowadays... I think flat files will bring you headaches. But if you really want to go this way, you may consider using XML. At least you have tons of tools and XPath.

Comment: Why don't you want to use a database? [The Android API has full support for SQLite](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/package-summary.html), it would almost be a mistake *not* to use it, unless your data isn't suitable for a database, e.g. it's a tree of some sort (in which case +1 @Leo).

Comment: You said "app" so I immediately assumed "Android" for some reason. That might not be correct. But even for desktop applications, SQLite is worth a look if you don't want to deal with setting up a server.

Comment: @JasonC: I think I love you. Thank for the suggestion, I think it is what I want :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few options you can look into:

- Store it in the cloud...for example one of the free tier options like S3 at Amazon ([AWS free tier explanation](http://aws.amazon.com/free/))
- Store it in a small embedded db like HSQLDB, embedded Derby, or H2
- Store it as some standard flat file format like XML which was mentioned by Leo

Really I can hardly imagine not using some kind of lightweight, embedded database because you will gain a lot of benefits and it will probably save you from implementing a lot of functionality and managing a lot of stuff that you don't really need to worry about. For what you described I'd go with the small embedded database route.